# Можно ли применить местоимение "то" к слову мужского или женского рода?

Tags: грамматика

Можно ли применить местоимение "то" к слову мужского или женского рода? Можно ли посмотрев на луну сказать"То луна" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, но не в таком контексте: "то" не употребляется по отношению к рассматриваемому в данный момент, и в этом примере возможно только "это". В подобных случах можно употребить "то" в порядке противопоставления чему-то, названному местоимением "это". Например: это (у нас перед глазами) луна, а вон то (в другом углу картины) - солнце. Для употребления местоимения "то" характерна некоторая удалённость обозначаемого в пространстве или времени, либо обозначаемое может быть предметом, о свойствах которого ранее подробно говорилось:

Ах, витязь, то была Наина!

Comment: Cпасибо ,а можно сказать" это солнце, а то луна", или "это лошадь а то осел", или "это учитель,а то инженер"?

Comment: Напрямую нельзя: по такой простой схеме можно только указывать на незнакомые предметы (порой, сопровождая речь жестом), один из которых ближе, другой дальше. Нужен особенный контекст. Он понял, почему на этой фотографии объект в небе ярче, чем на ранее ему показанной: это солнце, а то - (была) луна. Это лошадь Пржевальского, а то, что вы видите за забором - осёл. Вчера в офис заходил незнакомый человек, позже выяснилось, что то был инженер, искавший работу.

Comment: Alex_ander, здесь "то", вроде бы не местоимение, а указательная частица. Или как вариант - местоименное существительное. Как и "это" в подобных фразах. И она используется не вместо "тот" или "та", а в значении "то, о чем говорится". Так что я бы поостерегся на подобные ответы.

Comment: Но главное, что вопрос совершенно некорректный. "Можно ли сказать?".  Во-первых, можно Машку за ляжку, а по уставу - "разрешите".  А во-вторых, "ну скажи"...)))) Кто запрещает?